# org.hibernate.PropertyNotFoundException: Could not find setter for sum on class Class

Tags: sql, hibernate, criteria, hql

Pessoal estou tentando listar os produtos mais vendidos utilizando SQLQuery(se alguém souber de outra formas de realizar como por ex: usando Criteria, Projections também aceito) com Hibernate, porém está resultando esse erro:

```
    org.hibernate.PropertyNotFoundException: Could not find setter for sum on class pojo.ItemPedidoVenda
```

O código:

```
SQLQuery query = session.createSQLQuery("select sum(quantidade), produto_id from itempedidovenda group by produto_id order by sum(quantidade) desc");
    query.setResultTransformer(Transformers.aliasToBean(ItemPedidoVenda.class));
    List<ItemPedidoVenda> items = query.list();

    return query.list();
```

Comment: Amigo, eu coloquei uma resposta mas relendo o seu trecho do código estou com algumas duvidas.

`produto_id` é o sequencial de `ItemPedidoVenda`?
Você pretende retornar um resultado de `ItemPedidoVenda`?

Por que para mim, no momento, não faz sentido você pedir para o `select` retornar a soma de quantidade e o id do produto, enquanto pretende retornar o objeto inteiro.

Comment: Na verdade o campo produto_id é o id do produto na tabela itempedidovenda, eu gostaria de retornar o produto que mais "aparece" nessa tabela, utilizando o sql acima funciona (testei no SGBD), mas preciso realizar isso utilizando o HIBERNATE. Se puder me ajudar desde já agradeço.

Comment: Resposta editada @AlyssonOliveira, vê se te ajuda por favor.

Answer (score 1):

Utilizando Hibernate Query Language ([HQL](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.3/reference/pt-BR/html/queryhql.html)) (ou [JPQL](http://docs.oracle.com/html/E13946_05/ejb3_langref.html), não consigo diferencia-las), você induz o compilador à acreditar que existe um atributo `sum` dentro de `ItemPedidoVenda`.

Para resolver você poderia criar mesmo o atributo e colocar os seus `getters//setters` (pois é isso do que se trata o erro, não é encontrado `getSum` e `setSum`) ou utilizar SQL nativo e recuperar de um vetor de `Object`.

Eu deixarei a descrição acima pois é o que está errado de qualquer forma.

O que você deve perceber é que o HQL `select sum(quantidade), produto_id from ...` irá retornar um `Long` e o tipo da variavel que seja `produto_id`, então não há como converter isso para `ItemPedidoVenda`. o que você pode fazer é executar o seguinte HQL `SELECT MAX(SUM(ipv.quantidade)), ipv.produto_id FROM ItemPedidoVenda ipv`, retirar o retorno `ivp.produto` e utilizar em uma consulta em ItemPedidoVenda utilizando o código do objeto (`SELECT ipv FROM ItemPedidoVenda ipv  WHERE ipv.produto_id = :produtoId`). Em código ficaria algo assim.

```
query = createQuery("SELECT MAX(SUM(ipv.quantidade)), ipv.produto_id 
    FROM ItemPedidoVenda ipv");
Object[] resultados = query.getResult();
query = createQuery("SELECT ipv FROM ItemPedidoVenda ipv WHERE 
    ipv.produto_id = :produtoId");
query.setParameter(resultados[1]); //Trate aqui caso não tenha nada dentro de resultados;
ItemPedidoVenda objetoEsperado = query.getSingleResult();
```

Funcionaria até mesmo utilizando um subselect dentro do segundo select:

```
SELECT ipv FROM ItemPedidoVenda ipv WHERE ipv.produto_id = (
    SELECT produtoId FROM (
        SELECT MAX(SUM(ipv.quantidade)), ipv.produto_id as produtoId 
        FROM ItemPedidoVenda ipv
    )
)
```

Answer (score 0):

Do jeito que você está fazendo teria que ter um atributo na sua classe ItemPedidoVenda para guardar o sum. Nesse caso você especifica o alias com AS na consulta.
Assim:

```
SQLQuery query = session.createSQLQuery("select sum(quantidade) AS sum, produto......
```

lembrando que o atributo tem que ter o mesmo nome do alias.

Caso sua classe tenha o atributo valorDoSum (com get e set), você usa:

```
"select sum(quantidade) AS \"valorDoSum\", produto...
```

pra que ele procure um setValorDoSum em vez de setvalordosum.

Comment: Sua resposta pode ser melhorada adicionando informações fundamentais. Basta [edit] para adicionar mais detalhes, como citações ou documentação para que outras pessoas possam confirmar que sua resposta está correta. Você pode encontrar mais informações sobre como escrever boas respostas [na Central de Ajuda](/help/how-to-answer).